# Why is the bias term not regularized in ridge regression?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

In most of classifications (e.g. logistic / linear regression) the bias term is ignored while regularizing. Will we get better classification if we don't regularize the bias term?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Example:

```
Y = aX + b
```

Regularization is based on the idea that overfitting on `Y` is caused by `a` being "overly specific", so to speak, which usually manifests itself by large values of `a`'s elements.

`b` merely offsets the relationship and its scale therefore is far less important to this problem. Moreover, in case a large offset is needed for whatever reason, regularizing it will prevent finding the correct relationship.

So the answer lies in this: in `Y = aX + b`, `a` is multiplied with the explanatory/independent variable, `b` is added to it.

Comment: Why do you call `X` "explaining variable"? Is there some reference? thanks.

Comment: @Tyler提督九门步军巡捕五营统领, more commonly `X` would be referred to as the ["dependent variable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables).

Comment: @Def_Os, no, in this terminology `X` would be the _independent_ variable, and `Y` is the dependent one (`Y` depends on `X`). In response to @Tyler's question, the linked article mentions "explanatory variable" as a synonym for independent variable.